# Binding a Key to a Command in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I need help ending a loop of code by assigning a key to a command like the "a" key to exit but there cant be a pause I want the loop to run without you pressing the key on startup of the batch but when you press the key it stops the loop

```
@ECHO OFF 
:BEGIN 
CLS 
CHOICE /N /C:3 
IF ERRORLEVEL ==3 GOTO THREE 
GOTO END 
:THREE 
ECHO YOU HAVE PRESSED THREE 
GOTO END
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post the code.

Comment: I tried to find some code

Comment: @ECHO OFF
:BEGIN
CLS
CHOICE /N /C:3
IF ERRORLEVEL ==3 GOTO THREE
GOTO END
:THREE
ECHO YOU HAVE PRESSED THREE
GOTO END

Comment: but this is a choice which pauses the script

Comment: `IF ERRORLEVEL ==3` is wrong. Run `if /?` and see. And put code in backticks `\`like this\`` to make it readable

Answer (score 0):

The errorlevel does not correspond to the number in your choice value, it corresponds to the position. So in below example, 3 is the 1st character, therefore errorlevel = 1 for item 3 (being 1st item in the list)

```
@echo off
choice /C:345
if %errorlevel%==1 goto THREE
if %errorlevel%==2 goto FOUR
if %errorlevel%==3 goto FIVE
:THREE
echo Typed Three
goto END
:FOUR
echo Typed Four
goto END
:FIVE
echo Typed Five
goto END
:END
```